# Disable back button on specific page

Tags: reactjs, navigation

I'm trying to disable the back button on a specific page and cannot get it to work.

I am using hooks and I had tried doing things like

```
window.history.pushState(null, null, window.location.href);
        window.onpopstate = function () {
            window.history.go(1);
        };
```

If I set that on the page in a useEffect where I want the back button disabled, it disables any other page instead.

I also tried running a function inside the useEffect that does this:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    if (window.location = `/example`)
        window.history.pushState(null, null, window.location.href);
    window.onpopstate = function () {
        window.history.go();
    }
}, [])
```

That constantly runes in a loop if placed in a useEffect since the condition always returns true (because that route path matches) and it causes a re-render.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a sandbox, which prevents the back navigation on the second page.

https://codesandbox.io/s/disable-back-buton-ipstr

P.S. I wouldn't override the default behavior of the browser, unless absolutely necessary.